# TestNG - Retry test when configuration fails

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have Several hundred Selenium automated tests that (obviously) run in a browser, and sometimes they fail for no good reason.  I have a retry analyzer that will retry the test when the `@Test` fails, but is there anyway to retry the test if the `@BeforeMethod` or `@AfterMethod` fails?  I may an account creation method that runs in the `@BeforeMethod` that might fail randomly (but will pass if ran again) but since it was ran in the `@BeforeMethod` the entire test isn't retried.  I do have `configfailurepolicy="continue"` set in the XML file, so at least the rest of the tests will continue to run.

Comment: I believe configurations are not meant to be retried which perhaps is why there's no retry mechanism for config methods. But why not build the retry yourself by wrapping up the config method contents within a `while` loop which would re-attempt the configuration if there's a failure "n" times before giving up. Wouldn't that work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete and re-add the library to the project.
Note: Make sure you selected the correct path to the project directory which contain the library of that project

Comment: Can you please clarify as to how does your answer relate to the question ?